# Swap button and text in input type="file"

Tags: html, css

I want to swap text and button in input `type="file"`. Is it possible to use only html and css for this task or only js solutions are suitable?

Comment: Please provide us some code, showing what you have tried so far, and what problems you faced. You see, this is not a page where you get code for granted. We do not give free code here!

Answer (score 1):

Keywords are `::-webkit-file-upload-button` and [`::file-selector-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button). The solution will depend on browser version.

See also
[-webkit-file-upload-button css implementation for firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131419/webkit-file-upload-button-css-implementation-for-firefox)
or
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-file-upload-input-button-to-right-side-in-webkit/

Answer (score 0):

The input can be hidden and embedded between a label and a button. Javascript then carries over the functionality:

```
<label for="upload-file" style="width:130px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #ccc">Choose file</label>
<input id="upload-file" type="file" style="display:none" onchange="this.previousElementSibling.textContent = this.previousElementSibling.title = this.files[0].name"> 
<button onclick="this.previousElementSibling.click()">Browse...</button>
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/nxmwhsap/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to swap the text of a button when the button is clicked, you have to call a JS method, nothing fancy but just to retrieve the text from the input field since the user entered text can dynamically change.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="swapBtn" id="swapBtn" onclick="swapText()" value="button text">
<input type="text" id="inputTxt" class="inputTxt">
```

**JS**

```
function swapText()
{
    var textStr = document.getElementById("inputTxt").value;
    var btnEl = document.getElementById("swapBtn");
    btnEl.innerHTML = textStr;
}
```